# I cant make myHandler run

Tags: android, handler, android-handler

What I want to do is just a basic implementation of handler example. I have a `TextView` on the `mainActivity`, and once the page loads the handler is supposed to run and show the user value coming from `SystemClock.uptimeMillis`. But ıt doesn't work more than once. How can I make this code run?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    long uptoMS=0L;
    TextView tv;
    Handler handler=new Handler();
    long swaptime=0L;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        uptoMS=SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        tv.setText(String.valueOf(uptoMS));
        handler.post(runner);
    }

    private Runnable runner=new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            swaptime+=uptoMS;
            tv.setTag(String.valueOf(swaptime));
            handler.post(this);


        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See this below example

```
scheduler(){
  TimerTask tasknew = new TimerSchedulePeriod();
  Timer timer = new Timer();

  // scheduling the task at interval
  timer.schedule(tasknew,100, 100); 
 }

 // this method performs the task
 public void run() {
  System.out.println("timer working");      
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   timer = new Timer();
    refreshTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        swaptime+=uptoMS;
        tv.setTag(String.valueOf(swaptime));
        handler.post(this);
        }
    };

    timer.schedule(refreshTask,
            100, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there some problems with your code.

Firstly, you use setTag() instead of setText(), so the value will never update.

```
tv.setTag(String.valueOf(swaptime));
```

Secondly, you get uptoMS once in onCreate(), and then you use it in every "handler loop". I don't know what you try to achive but it's unlike that you want this.

Thirdly, you instantly repost your Runnable, so the main thread's message queue will be busy. You should give some break instead of instant reposting. For example you can wait 100 ms between the updates, so the TextView will be updated 10 times in every second.

```
handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
```

And finally, however others suggest you using Timer, just ignore them. Handler is the Android way to achieve tasks like this.